# Emai verification system testing PHP, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, registration

I am currently building an online registry system and one of its modules is the registration system.

After a user successfully register, a verification email is sent to his/her email address. I followed every tutorial I read online and I'm still getting the same problem.

here's what i got so far:

```
//this is what it looks like in my controller after validation of fields from registration
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");  
        $this->email->from('my_personal_email@gmail.com', 'Mike Lee');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

        if($this->email->send()){
            //this is to check if email is sent
            redirect('site/registered');
        }else{
            //else error
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
```

for my configuration of email.php:

```
class CI_Email {

var $useragent      = "CodeIgniter";
var $mailpath       = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"; // Sendmail path
var $protocol       = "smtp";   // mail/sendmail/smtp
var $smtp_host      = "https://smtp.googlemail.com";        // SMTP Server.  Example: mail.earthlink.net
var $smtp_user      = "my_personal_email@gmail.com";        // SMTP Username
var $smtp_pass      = "my_personal_emailpassword";      // SMTP Password
var $smtp_port      = "25";     // SMTP Port
var $smtp_timeout   = 10;       // SMTP Timeout in seconds
var $smtp_crypto    = "";       // SMTP Encryption. Can be null, tls or ssl.
var $wordwrap       = TRUE;     // TRUE/FALSE  Turns word-wrap on/off
var $wrapchars      = "76";     // Number of characters to wrap at.
var $mailtype       = "text";   // text/html  Defines email formatting
var $charset        = "utf-8";  // Default char set: iso-8859-1 or us-ascii
var $multipart      = "mixed";  // "mixed" (in the body) or "related" (separate)
var $alt_message    = '';       // Alternative message for HTML emails
var $validate       = FALSE;    // TRUE/FALSE.  Enables email validation
var $priority       = "3";      // Default priority (1 - 5)
var $newline        = "\n";     // Default newline. "\r\n" or "\n" (Use "\r\n" to comply with RFC 822)
var $crlf           = "\n";     // The RFC 2045 compliant CRLF for quoted-printable is "\r\n".  Apparently some servers,
                                // even on the receiving end think they need to muck with CRLFs, so using "\n", while
                                // distasteful, is the only thing that seems to work for all environments.
var $send_multipart = TRUE;     // TRUE/FALSE - Yahoo does not like multipart alternative, so this is an override.  Set to FALSE for Yahoo.
var $bcc_batch_mode = FALSE;    // TRUE/FALSE  Turns on/off Bcc batch feature
var $bcc_batch_size = 200;      // If bcc_batch_mode = TRUE, sets max number of Bccs in each batch
var $_safe_mode     = FALSE;
var $_subject       = "";
var $_body          = "";
var $_finalbody     = "";
var $_alt_boundary  = "";
var $_atc_boundary  = "";
var $_header_str    = "";
var $_smtp_connect  = "";
var $_encoding      = "8bit";
var $_IP            = FALSE;
var $_smtp_auth     = FALSE;
var $_replyto_flag  = FALSE;
var $_debug_msg     = array();
var $_recipients    = array();
var $_cc_array      = array();
var $_bcc_array     = array();
var $_headers       = array();
var $_attach_name   = array();
var $_attach_type   = array();
var $_attach_disp   = array();
var $_protocols     = array('mail', 'sendmail', 'smtp');
var $_base_charsets = array('us-ascii', 'iso-2022-');   // 7-bit charsets (excluding language suffix)
var $_bit_depths    = array('7bit', '8bit');
var $_priorities    = array('1 (Highest)', '2 (High)', '3 (Normal)', '4 (Low)', '5 (Lowest)');
```

here's the error:

/*
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:25 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689
*/

i use my personal email acct to send test mail. but i don't know if that will work with gmail. can you somehow enlighten me how i can test if my code is working? or is there a software that can be used as my test server to send mail?

thanks. :(

Comment: try changing the     var $smtp_port      = "465";

Comment: so that's it. google mail uses 465 as its port. [solved] :D

Comment: Glad I could be of help, also you helped me to actually! I didn't know you could choose between TLS or SSL :D

Comment: It used port 465 if your sending encrypted emails (you can use 25 if your sending unencrypted emails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all the tutorials I have seen, and from all the apps I have used, I have only ever used 465 as my port to connect with google email. Also correct me if I am wrong but you are editing the actual library? Since I see class Email at the top of the code you pasted. What you should do is go into the application/config directory, and make a php file called email.php Then the contents of that file should include : (this is my contents, you can obviously change it)

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = '';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_timeout'] = 30;
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['crlf'] = "\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['priority'] = 1;
$config['validate'] = TRUE;
```

Some issues in your case was that you are trying to send encrypted emails through an un-encrypted port (25). [Based on this useful reading](https://www.fastmail.fm/help/technology_ssl_vs_tls_starttls.html) :

> **SMTP uses port 25, but SSL/TLS encrypted SMTP uses port 465**

So you have a inconsistency of the port number and the protocol you wanted to use.

Comment: Look at the comment above. And yes you should continue to use SSL/TLS so maintain the port 465